# Sorting and paging GridView issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, paging

i'm using a `GridView` and trying to sort and page it.
I have more than 20 rows on my DataBase, but the GridView just shows 10.
I set `AllowPaging=true` but noting happened.
Also I'm using `AllowSorting = true` and `OnSorting="GridView_Sorting"`. But when I click on the header to sort the the content of that column, it does not enters on my `OnSorting="GridView_Sorting"` it goes right to the `GridView1_RowCommand` why ?
Sometimes it just give me this error:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object error`

Here's my Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;" 

    CssClass="gridview" OnSorting="GridView_Sorting"
    AllowSorting ="True" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
    BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="2px" BorderColor="GrayText"
    CellPadding="1"
    CellSpacing="5"
    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    ForeColor = "Black" RowStyle-CssClass="gridview" 
    OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">            
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
       <columns>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id" SortExpression="id"  />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PRIORIDADE" DataField="prioridade" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="prioridade" SortExpression="prioridade" />
          <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="SITUAÇÃO"  DataField="situacao" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RESPONSAVEL" DataField="responsavel" HeaderStyle-Width="65px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
          <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DATA DE CADASTRO" DataField="dt_cadastro" SortExpression="dt_cadastro" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-Width="60px"ItemStyleHorizontalAlign="Center" >
          <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PREVISÃO DE TÉRMINO" DataField="previsao_termino" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderStyle-Width="60px"
          ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
          <HeaderStyle Width="60px" />
          <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          </asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PROJETO" DataField="projeto"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FUNCIONALIDADE" DataField="funcionalidade" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CLUBE" DataField="clube"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="70px" HeaderText="VISUALIZAR" >
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="Btn_Visualizar" runat="server" Text="VISUALIZAR" CssClass="Btn_Grid"  Font-Size="7pt" Font-Names="Verdana, Arial"  OnClick="Btn_Visualizar_Click"CommandName="visualizar" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />                            
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="66px" HeaderText="ALTERAR">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Button ID="Btn_Alterar" runat="server" Text="ALTERAR" CssClass="Btn_Grid" Font-Size="7pt" Font-Names="Verdana, Arial"CommandName="editar" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />
          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="66px" HeaderText="FEEDBACK">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="Btn_Feedback" runat="server" Text="ADICIONAR" CssClass="Btn_Grid" Font-Size="7pt" Font-Names="Verdana,Arial"CommandName="feedback" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>" />
       </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       </columns>
```

My CodeBehind:

```
protected void GridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] strSortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString().Split(' ');

            // If the sorting column is the same as the previous one,  
            // then change the sort order. 
            if (strSortExpression[0] == e.SortExpression) 
                { 
                if (strSortExpression[1] == "ASC") 
                { 
                    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC"; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC"; 
                } 
            } 
                // If sorting column is another column,   
                // then specify the sort order to "Ascending". 
            else 
            { 
                ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC"; 
            } 
            // Rebind the GridView control to show sorted data. 
            GridView1.DataSource = ch.BuscaTodosChamados();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add SortExpression attribute for each sortable column, informing its DataField.

Comment: I updated my code some minuts ago... I already did that, then instead it goes to the `GridView_Sorting`event that I set on the `OnSorting` event... It goes right to `RowCommand` event. Why ?

Comment: It's a common behavior from any GridView clicking event. It's up to you to check which command fired the event (using CommandName property). However it doesn't prevent you to sort the grid. Right after passing through RowCommand event, the Sorting event will be called.

Comment: I updated my question, look my codebehind... It still not sorting =\

Comment: also I cant paging, or scrollbar it ;s any help ?

Comment: Is it reaching the Sorting event at least? I mean, does it hit any breakpoint?

Comment: It is going to the Sorting event, after it pass through the Row_Command Event.